# How to handle acknowledging a Pubsub streampull subscription message?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to streampull messages that I receive from cloudrun source which is sending the messages to a topic, while I am trying to process and acknowledge the messages back to pubsub I am receiving error messages as

> google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.exceptions.AcknowledgeError: None AcknowledgeStatus.INVALID_ACK_ID (AcknowledgeError when lease-modacking a message.
> )

When using pubsub_v1 subscriber in python application ,how to properly process and acknowledge the messages and do we need to set any parameters for pull subscriptions to handle these invalid ids?

Here is the callback code that is throwing an error at bolded statements?

```
using   subscriber2.acknowledge(request={"subscription":subscription_path2,"ack_ids":[ack_id]}) to acknowledege the recived message ids
```

[Acknowledment code part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcEPi.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77197384/gcp-pub-sub-pull-subscription-consumer-with-jpa-backed-repos-resulting-in-connec/77956310#77956310

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Pub/Sub client library, you just need to call `message.ack()` to acknowledge a message. There is no need to call the acknowledge API directly. The `INVALID_ACK_ID` error indicates you are using exactly once delivery. Note that the message says "AcknowledgeError when **lease-modacking** a message." This indicates a failure not in acknowledging the message, but in extending its ack deadline.

This error message may happen if the ack and a lease modack go back to the server at around the same time and the ack is processed first. In such a case, the modack is no longer valid because the ack on the message has occurred. The error does not mean that your message was not acknowledged.

When using exactly once delivery, you can use [`ack_with_response()`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#pubsub_subscriber_exactly_once-python) to see the result of your ack and ensure it was processed.

Comment: This is generating a lot of error noise in the logs. Am I expected to just catch this and swallow it or is there a setting I should use on the client to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any conclusive answer but I used after the imports:

```
logging.getLogger('google.cloud.pubsub_v1').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

This supressed the warnings and thus all logs in google cloud. It's not a satisfactory solution though, as it supresses all logs with a lower level than error...

I guess this bug should be solved by Google.